# Python 3.10 - iterating through directory of files says "this file does not exist"

Tags: python, filereader

### summary

Creating a Python 3.10 program to read a directory of mp3 files and produce a playlist. I would like this program to be portable across operating systems so it would just use the relative path to mp3files instead of a full OS path.

No matter what filespec I use getting error with the file name - so it's reading the filename from the os spec - was not found.

### structure

- mp3reader (directory)

  - reader.py
  - mp3files (directory)

    - a.mp3
    - b.mp3

### reader.py

```
import os

mp3dir="mp3files"

# Iterate over the MP3 files in the directory
for mp3_file in os.listdir(mp3dir):

    # Check if the file exists
    if os.path.exists(mp3_file):
        print(str(os.path.getsize(mp3_file)))
    else:
        print("The file {} does not exist.".format(mp3_file))
```

### result

The file a.mp3 does not exist.

The file b.mp3 does not exist.

### have tried

- mp3dir="mp3files"
- mp3dir="mp3reader/mp3files"
- mp3dir="mp3reader\mp3files"
- mp3dir="(full-path-to-directory)/mp3reader/mp3files"
- mp3dir="r(full-path-to-directory)/mp3reader/mp3files"
- mp3dir="r(full-path-to-directory)\mp3reader\mp3files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listdir()` will not return a full path, so unless your current working directory is where your mp3 files live, you will not find them. To solve that, build full, absolute path to your files on-the fly and use it for further processing. That way it's irrelevant where these files are, as long as the full path you constructed is correct and you got the access:

```py
import os

mp3dir = "mp3files"
mp3dir_full = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mp3dir))

# Iterate over the MP3 files in the directory
for mp3_file in os.listdir(mp3dir_full):

    # construct absolute path to the mp3 file:
    mp3_file_full = os.path.join(mp3dir_full, mp3_file)

    # Check if the file exists
    if os.path.exists(mp3_file_full):
        print(str(os.path.getsize(mp3_file_full)))
    else:
        print("The file {} does not exist.".format(mp3_file_full))
```